# Wordpress theme options framework, I can't read them in my templates

Tags: theme-options, options, framework

I successfully created my theme options page using this framework:

https://github.com/devinsays/options-framework-theme

The problems Is that when, for example, I try to load the Option: 'logo_image'

```
global $options; var_dump($options); /* dumps NULL */
```

and

```
foreach ($options as $value) { 
    if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) {
        $$value['id'] = $value['std'];
    } else {
        $$value['id'] = get_settings( $value['id'] );
    } 
    echo $$value['id']; /*prints nothing*/
}
```

And

```
echo get_option(‘logo_image’);   /* also prints nothing */
```

This is how I am calling the framework in my functions.php

```
if ( !function_exists( 'optionsframework_init' ) ) {
    define( 'OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/' );
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/options-framework.php';
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've done everything correctly during the setup, then you should be able to load the logo_image option like this:

```
$my_theme_prefix_option = of_get_option('logo_image');
```

Comment: aaaaaaaah!!!! of_ (options framework, right?)

Comment: Exactly. :) Are you able to retrieve the option now?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot! I wish I posted this sooner... :)